# Jenkins Slaves with Docker

Tags: docker, jenkins, build

So I’ve been seeing this trend to use docker to spin up Jenkins slaves and I have a doubt regarding the use of same.

Let’s say I have a strong box for my master and another one very decent (ram, cpu, etc).

Would guys recommend spin up 2,3, etc docker-Jenkins slaves (all of them pointing to different ssh port)? Should I use another box and spin up another container there?

What would you think it’s the best?

I know it really depends on the project you are building and all that stuff. But keeping that aside, is it a good practice?

Answer (score 2):

An even more interesting approach is to use [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/), in addition of Docker.

That way, with the [Jenkins Kubernetes plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin), you can run dynamic agents in a Kubernetes cluster.
You don't have a fixed number of agents anymore: you can scale with as many agent as needed (and as many your cluster can support)

Plus, you can [specify your pod template](https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin#pipeline-support) to use as a slave, meaning your container with all the right executable installed in it for a particular job to use.

Comment: I see that with Kubernetes plugin and pod template, we can create dynamic slaves with image "jenkins/inbound-agent:4.3-4"  however this doesn't contain docker in itself to build a dockerfile with this slave. Is there any way to have docker also installed in the "jenkins/inbound-agent:4.3-4" image ?

Comment: @MayankGokarna Why not using directly the agent for building your Dockerfile, instead of a dynamic slave? See https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/